# Footer does not stretch on page scroll bounce

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, vite

In my react vite project I struggel with my footer that does not stretch when the page scrolls to the end and the bounce effect occurs. This bounce effect leads to the footer losing hold of the lower left and right corner and the primary color comes to show, which is not desired.

Approach:
I've set the background color of the body to the desired color but this causes all the other section elements About, Experience, Portfolio, and Contact to inherit this color. I've also set the container of the Footer to flex grow without this having an effect. Should the approach be to make the footer stretch (event though it's subborn enought to not) or set the color of a background container to the desired color, and set all the section element to the primary color to not make the color palette all crazy?

video:
https://vimeo.com/850126196?share=copy

App.jsx (parent to footer)

```
  <BrowserRouter>
  <div className='relative z-0 flex flex-col min-h-screen '>
    {!lampToggle && (
      <Navbar
        heroRef={heroRef}
        animationClass={navbarAnimate ? 'navbar-animate' : ''}
        selectedLang={selectedLang}
        setSelectedLang={setSelectedLang}
      />
    )}
    <div className='flex-grow-1 page-container '>
      <div className='relative z-0'>
        <Hero
          setLampToggleApp={() => setLampToggle(!lampToggle)}
          ref={heroRef}
        />
      </div>

      <About />
      <Experience />

      <Works onProjectClick={handleModalClick} />

      {showModal && (
        <ProjectModal
          modalProject={modalProject}
          onClose={() => setShowModal(false)}
        />
      )}
      <Feedbacks />

      <div className='relative z-0'>
        <Contact />
        <StarsCanvas />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Footer.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer = () => {
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const yourName = '© K';

return (
<div
  className='absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 w-full bg-black 
  text-white flex justify-center items-center text-sm p-2'
  style={{ zIndex: '9999' }}
   >
  <p className='garet-book'>{yourName}</p>
  <p className='garet-book ml-2'>{currentYear}</p>
  </div>
  );
 };
```

export default Footer;

Comment: please add a code like a snippet and add tailwind or whatever to it. or an admin or ...